# Angular2: Nesting a child component doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've been playing around with angular 2 for a few days now. I'm trying to insert a child selector into a parent template. It should be simple enough but I can't for the life of me get it to work. I get the following error:

"Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'child' is not a known element:"

Where am i going wrong? Can someone please take me out of my misery??

```js
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChildModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
//app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  entryComponents: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

```html
  

  <!-- app.component.html -->
    <h1>
      {{title}}
    </h1>
    <child></child>
```

```js
//child.module.ts
@NgModule({
    declarations:[ChildComponent]
})
export class ChildModule{}
```

```js
   

 //child.component.ts
    @Component({
        selector:'child',
        templateUrl: './child.component.html'
    })
    export class ChildComponent{
        
    }
```

```html
   

 <!-- child.component.html -->
    <h1>child</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to export your component:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[ChildComponent],
    exports :[ChildComponent]
})
export class ChildModule{}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your rapid reply. That worked. I will mark as answered as soon as I am allowed. FYI the property is "exports" rather than "export"